What is the minimal setup for a Catholic mass?
I discussed with a friend about the absolute minimum required to have a mass, and I found it particularly difficult to find documentation about these requirements.
The obvious one (for me at least) is a priest, or someone allowed to perform a mass. We were not clear about anything else, my friend also mentioned that a priest always wears a stole when proceeding to sacraments.
Is there a documented minimal set of elements and people required for a mass to be held?
EDIT following the comments: I was hoping for a document that states something along the lines of "in order for a mass to be licit, it must be performed by XXX and YYY, ZZZ must be used".

In canon law nearly every requirement can be waived if there is a true necessity. Are you interested in this case or in the minimal requirements, if everything more could be obtained?

And: Are you interested in the minimal setup for a valid or a licit mass?

IANAP, but I think what they sell in the Mass Kits constitutes a minimum - whether it is the minimum, I do not know.

@PeterTurner: I edited your edit because I meant "perform a mass" (not sure about the proper wording)

@K-HB: I edited my question with a clarification, I am more interested in the non-critical cases (a spontaneous mass in the woods during a trekking for instance)

Priests in prison have said mass with no vestments and simply having bread and wine to consecrate the bread and wine into the Body and Blood of Christ while reciting the Roman Canon by heart!

@KenGraham  I've been told that wine can be grape juice that has only slightly fermented (and that priests in prison have used that).  On the other hand, I'm not so confident that the canon suffices; I'd think you'd need  at least part of an offertory too (maybe the prayers "Suscipe sancte Pater ..." and "Offerimus tibi ...").

There are some distinctions to make. First, we can talk about what is necessary for a valid mass, vs invalid, and then we can also talk about what is necessary for a licit mass during ordinary circumstances, vs a licit mass during extraordinary circumstances.
First, validity is easy to answer. A valid Mass requires merely the validly ordained priest, bread made from wheat flour, grape wine with a bit of water that can be mixed in, and the words hoc est enim corpus meum and hoc est enim calix sanguinis mei, or the semantic equivalent. That is the bare minimum for a valid consecration of the Eucharist - what makes a Mass a Mass. If any of these components are missing, the Mass is invalid.
What is necessary for a licit Mass can be found by examining the Code of Canon Law, the General Instruction on the Roman Missal, and the text of the Mass itself. Canons 924-933 give general norms for what is and isn't licit concerning the circumstances of celebrating a Mass. These outline the how, when, and where. The GIRM gives far more detail as to the how. And, if you look at the text of the Mass itself, that needs to be followed to the letter for liceity, at least in ordinary circumstances.
General and particular dispensations can be given for emergencies and other extraordinary circumstances, so that a mass may still be licit in the face of deviation from the norms. Such a dispensation must be given by a bishop with territorial authority to give it in order for the dispensation to be licit. There are some cases where even a dispensation would seem to be impossible in order to recover liceity, such as with canon 927, which states "It is absolutely forbidden, even in extreme urgent necessity, to consecrate one matter without the other or even both outside the eucharistic celebration."
